# Куда вставить код соц. кнопок от Яндекс?

Tags: javascript, joomla, ya-share2

Добрый день! Я далек от написания кодов, могу только вставить готовый код в нужное место, если мне скажут где это место. Как со счетчиком Яндекса - в ставьте код туда и туда, и все работает. А вот с кодом социальных сетей - не все так гладко. Подскажите куда его точно вставить, что бы он отображался после каждой статьи. И еще:

1. "Подключите скрипт блока" -  вставить его куда-то в код страницы?
2. "Поместите блок в контейнер. В качестве контейнера можно использовать любой блочный элемент, добавив атрибут `class="ya-share2"`"- поместить (то есть заключить весь код соц. кнопок между тегами `<div ..../<div>`?) весь полученный от Яндекса код или его часть, которая еще не помещена в контейнер?

Сайт на Joomle.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите статью [здесь](http://ktonanovenkogo.ru/seo/smo/knopki-socialnyx-setej-sajta-joomla-wordpress-oficialnye-knopki-samodelny-blok-podelitsya-yandeks.html).

> В Joomla для вставки этого блока, наверное, проще всего будет
>   воспользоваться модулем Произвольного Html кода, расположив его в
>   позиции шаблона где-нибудь сразу под текстом статьи.

Comment: Легких путей мы не ищим. Но если не получиться с кодом, то придется идти к плагинам! Где то нашел, что первую половину - скрипт надо ставить в шапку кода, а вторую часть сами кнопки куда пожелаете. После эксперементов этих да еще с div сайт упал! Хорошо что делал 2 дня назад копию! Поменял целиком файл и все вернулось! Вставлял в HTML код(вторую часть) ни чего не где не появилось! Надо попробовать целиком всавить! О результате от пишусь.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы затрудняетесь работать с отдельным кодом я бы посоветовал установить готовый плагин для социальных кнопок, после установки и активации плагина кнопки автоматически добавятся в контенте [Плагин](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/bt-social-sharing/)

Также можете настроить плагин так как вам удобно будет и всё автоматом будет работать )